# adding an item to the shopping cart does not add the first time; it does add the second time

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

This has been happening for a long time - when I add an item to the shopping cart the first time - it does not add to cart! The second time it does add...

My Magento version is  `Magento 1.9.1.0`

This does not happen always but every once in a while. Magento Cache is enabled.

Comment: Is the `frontend` cookie being set correctly on the first page load?